# Add key bindings to JButtons that get their actions from action commands?

Tags: java, swing, action, keymapping

I found a cool way in another question to create a JButton whose actions are written and viewed in an easy way:

```
public JButton makeToolbarButton(String title, String actionCommand) {
    JButton button = new JButton(title);
    button.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    return button;
}
```

The class this method is in implements ActionListener, and the buttons commands are assigned by:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int action = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
    switch(action) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("This button pressed.");
        break;
    }
}
```

And the buttons are made by:

```
    JButton button1 = makeToolbarButton("Button 1", "1");
```

So my question is: can I add KeyStrokes to a button by this method? I tried something like this (inside of the `makeToolbarButton` method):

```
    button.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("B"), "button_pressed");
    button.getActionMap().put("button_pressed", button.getAction());
```

But I figure this doesn't work because the action command isn't actually assigning an action to a specific button. Is there a way to add something to the `makeToolbarButton()` method and a parameter for the KeyStroke to accomplish this?

Comment: `button.getAction()` isn't going to work, as you've not assigned an `Action` to the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of the `Action` API.  A `Action` is intended to provide a single, self contained, unit of work.  This means that the `actionCommand` really isn't required, as when the `actionListener` event is triggered, you know exactly the context in which it's been executed

I'd also avoid using `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(String)`, as the text is a verbose description of what you want to do (ie `pressed B` or something, but needless to say, it's a pain to get right)

So, the following demonstrates how you might use `Action`s and assign them to a button AND a key binding

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ActionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ActionTest();
    }

    public ActionTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            add(createButton(new ActionOne(), KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0)));
            add(createButton(new ActionTwo(), KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2, 0)));
        }

        public JButton createButton(Action action, KeyStroke keyStroke) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(action);
            btn.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, "button_pressed");
            btn.getActionMap().put("button_pressed", action);
            return btn;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class ActionOne extends AbstractAction {

        public ActionOne() {
            putValue(NAME, "1");
            putValue(Action.ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "Action.one");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        }

    }

    public class ActionTwo extends AbstractAction {

        public ActionTwo() {
            putValue(NAME, "2");
            putValue(Action.ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "Action.two");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        }

    }

}
```

See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: I figured I would have to individually add actions. I was just wondering if there was a quick and easy way to use a String for the KeyStrokes. I'll add your solution to my program. Thanks!