# Execute the ActionListener of a button when I press just one key

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keyevent

I'm writing my first calculator in Java Swing and I would like, when I press for example "1" of my keyboard, it execute the `ActionListener` of my button.

No "ALT-1" or "CTRL-1", just the key "1".

Here is an example of my buttons :

```
 n0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String nombre0 = Integer.toString(nb0);
            textFieldAns.setText(textFieldAns.getText() + nombre0);
        }
    });
```

I don't know if you want an another parts of my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add key bindings to JButtons that get their actions from action commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601591/add-key-bindings-to-jbuttons-that-get-their-actions-from-action-commands)

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses a `KeyListener` to detect keyboard activity.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739623/how-to-add-a-shortcut-key-for-a-jbutton-in-java/33739732#33739732. It demonstrates how to use Key Bindings to share a common Action.

Comment: I try all of your tips and liks but nothing work :/